# Automat js form calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need help with a js/jQuery automat form calculator.

The function is `time=games*(players*15)`,
so basically there are 3 form fields `games` `players` result in field `time`.

I want the result to be in real time not by pressing a button.

Here is the code I made with a trigger button, but I want without calculate button, just by completing fields.

Nvm, I resolved it with an `onChance` for fields.

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function CalculateSum(games, players, form)
{
var A = parseFloat(games);
var B = parseFloat(players);
form.Time.value = A*(B*15) ;
}

function ClearForm(form)s
{
form.input_A.value = "";
form.input_B.value = "";
form.Time.value = "";
}

// end of JavaScript functions -->
</SCRIPT>

// HTML -->
<FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="post">
<P>Games: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_A" SIZE=10></P>
<P>Plyers <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_B" SIZE=10></P>
<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate time" name="Calculate time" 
onClick="CalculateSum(this.form.input_A.value, this.form.input_B.value, this.form)"></P>
<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Clear" name="Clear" onClick="ClearForm(this.form)"></P>
<P>Time = <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Time" SIZE=12></P>
</FORM>
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand this - could you provide more examples?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `keyup()` to trigger the function so the result is update everytime the user add a number

Answer (score 0):

You can use keyup to trigger when you enter a value

```js
function CalculateSum()
{
var games = $('input[name=input_A]').val()
var players = $('input[name=input_B]').val()
var time = parseFloat(games) * (parseFloat(players) * 15)
$('input[name=Time]').val(time)
}

function ClearForm()
{
  $('input[name=input_A], input[name=input_B], input[name=Time]').val('')
  
}

// bind view 
$('input[name=input_A], input[name=input_B]').on('keyup', function(){
  CalculateSum()
})

$('input[name=Clear]').on('click', function(){
  ClearForm()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="post">
<P>Games: <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_A" SIZE=10></P>
<P>Plyers <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="input_B" SIZE=10></P>
<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Clear" name="Clear"></P>
<P>Time = <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Time" SIZE=12></P>
</FORM>
```